# Determining a meromorphic function from its poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on an old qual question.  Suppose we have a function $f(z)$ meromorphic on the extended complex plane.  The only poles are $-1$, which has principal part $1/(z+1)$, and $2$, which has principal part $2/(z-2)+4/(z-2)^3$.

The first part of the question asks for $\int_{|z|=4} f(z) \: dz$, which is clearly $6 \pi i$.

The next part asks for the number of solutions to $f(z)=1$ in the extended complex plane.  I  know $$f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{(z-2)^3(z+1)}$$ for some polynomial $p(z)$ with degree $\leq 4$ and $p(0)=-8$.  So $f(z)=1 \iff p(z)-(z-2)^3(z+1)=0$, so there are $4$ finite solutions, counting multiplicity.  How do we determine if $f(\infty)=1$?

Finally, the last part asks to determine $f(z)$ explicitly, and I am stuck on this.

Comment: There are not necessarily always four finite solutions (counting multiplicity). There are fewer if and only if $f(\infty) = 1$. Can you see why?

Comment: $f(\infty)$, by definition, means $\lim_{w\to 0} f(1/w)$. For rational functions like this, that's a good way to calculate $f(\infty)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Since $p(z)$ is relatively prime to the denominator, call it $D(z)$, it seems like any solution to $p(z)-D(z)=0$ is a solution to $f(z)=1$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @TorsionSquid $p(z) - D(z)$ is a polynomial. What is its degree?

Comment: Oh wait...I see.  $p(z)$ might cancel off some terms of $D(z)$, making the difference a lower-degree polynomial.

Comment: Exactly. And that happens if and only if ...

Comment: Thanks, I understand your first comment now.

Comment: For the last part, you have the slight problem that $f$ is not uniquely determined so far. You can add constants.